# job history log file

Tags: logging, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have program which uses hadoop vaidya tool.
http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/vaidya.html

`$HADOOP_HOME/contrib/vaidya/bin/vaidya.sh -jobconfig <path1> -joblog <path2>`

I am not able tofound job history; where can I find the job history log file in hadoop?

**Thanks In Advance !**

Answer (score 1):

When your MR job finishes and has output to a location in HDFS, check that HDFS output folder - you should see a `_logs` folder, which contains a history folder, which in turn contains the two files you are after (the job conf XML and a job history log)

Comment: Anything wrong with this answer, cldo? If not accept, if not please elaborate.